# How can I override Bootstrap css with my child theme css in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to load my site's child theme's css after Bootstrap CDN css in wordpress. I tried using these code but it doesn't work. The Bootstrap css is not overriden. What should I do to fix that?

```
function override_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'override_css' );
```